# Showing $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x^4}=\infty$ via $\epsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

> Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x^4}=\infty$.

Consider our preliminary work:
$$\begin{align}
|\frac{1}{x^4}-0|<\epsilon &\implies|x^4-0|<\frac{1}{\epsilon}  \tag1\\
&\implies|x^2-0||x^2+0|<\frac{1}{\epsilon} \tag2\\
&\implies|x-0||x+0||x^2+0|<\frac{1}{\epsilon} \tag3
\end{align}$$
Choose $\delta=1$, then
$$|x-0|<\delta=1\implies -1<x<1\Rightarrow|x-0|<1 \tag4$$
Thus,
$$|x-0||x+0||x^2+0|<\frac{1}{\epsilon}\implies|x-0|<\frac{1}{\epsilon} \tag5$$ Now, let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta= \min\{1,\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}$.

What should I do next in writing this proof? I'm confused how to choose $\delta$ so that  $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ becomes $\epsilon$. Also, do I need to pick multiple upper bounds since I broke my polynomial into three separate absolute values?

Comment: A few issues: The limit is to $\infty$, not to zero, so you are not bounding $\frac1{x^4}$ from above. Inequalities switches direction when taking reciprocals, and why do you insist having $\pm0$ in every step?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just trying to follow this definition. Recall that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=\infty$ means that for all $M>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|x-c|<\delta$, it follows that $f(x)>M$.

Comment: "It follows that f(x) > M," then why does it say $|\dfrac{1}{x^4}| < \epsilon$ in your preliminary work? Edit: should it not be > M?

Comment: Absolutely  very little clue what I'm doing. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to find M, so I thought it was supposed to be in the fashion of an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.

Comment: You are not supposed to find M. Given M you should find some $\delta>0$ such that  $\frac{1}{x^4} >M$ for all $|x|<\delta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be given. Then, take $\delta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{M}}$. Thus,

$$0< |x| < \delta \implies |x| < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{M}} \implies |x^4| < \dfrac{1}{M} \implies |\dfrac{1}{x^4}| > M $$

Comment: That makes sense, at least. Why are you starting with $|x|$ and not $|\frac{1}{x^4}|$?

Comment: I did the preliminary work. Since I do not need to provide information on *how* I chose my delta but only need to state what delta *is*, I omitted that rough part.

Comment: I *could* have started with $|\dfrac{1}{x^4}| > M$ since these are all equivalent statements. Maybe it's improper to put $\implies$ and rather I should put $\iff$. However, since we assume that $0 < |x| < \delta$, the proof would look 'backwards'.

Comment: Duh! Thanks for the explanation, before I read your second comment, I scribbled it out myself. Thanks for the input, I'll mark your answer as the accepted solved answer!